# Passing function code in a class constructor

Tags: c++

i was wondering if it's possible to pass a code function into a constructor of a class in c++ ?

class.hpp

```
class A {
    public:
        A(void (*f)( parameters ... );
    private:
        void comp( parameters ...);
}
```

class.cpp

```
#include "class.hpp"
A::A(void (*f)( parameters ....) {
    &comp = &f;
}
```

The idea behind is i want to have a comparaison function that i can instantiate when i create my object.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Sure you can, but comp is a function declaration, not a pointer as you declared it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, anyway the syntax to declare a function pointer isn't the one you used:

```
class A {
    public:
        A(void (*f)( int a ) ) : comp(f) {};
    private:
        void (*comp)( int a ); // Function pointer
};

void comparisonFun(int a) {
 //...   
}

int main()
{
    A obj(comparisonFun);
}
```

by doing

```
class A {
    public:
        A(void (*f)( parameters ... );
    private:
        void comp( parameters ...);
}
```

you were declaring a `comp` function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do this. Define a type of function pointer, like PFN here, then use it a parameter type when passing as function pointer for elegance.

```
void somefn(int a, char c) {
    // do something
}

typedef void (*PFN)(int, char);

class A {
    public:
        A(PFN pf);
    private:
        PFN comp;
};

A::A(PFN pf) {
    comp = pf;
}

int main()
{
    A a(somefn);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you make the member a function-pointer type

```
void (*comp)(/*parameters*/);
```

and assign the value, as you would any other type

```
comp = f;
```

or, if you prefer, initialise it in the constructor's initialiser list

```
A(void (*f)(/*parameters*/)) : comp(f) {}
```

You might find it more convenient to use a type alias, since function pointer types are slightly fiddly to type

```
typedef void Comp(/*parameters*/);
Comp * comp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and use [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) expression to initialise the function

```
class A {
    public:
        typedef std::function<void(int,int)> CompFun;

        A(CompFun f) : comp(f) { }
    private:
        CompFun comp;
};
```

And then call the constructor with the lambda passed to it:

```
A a([](int a, int b) 
    { 
        return a < b; 
    });
```